# Javascript change value when choose on select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<center>
<div class="main">
  <div class="harga">Rp.2,680,000 / Bln</div>
  <div class="other">Kontrak Setahun
  atau <label>Rp. 2,930,000 / Bln</label></div>
  </br>
  <div class="traffic">Pilih traffic Anda dibawah ini</div>
  <select class="visitor">
    <option value="5,000">Up To 5,000</option>
    <option value="7,900">Up To 7,900</option>
    <option value="17,600">Up To 17,600</option>
    <option value="25,000">Up To 25,000</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  Visitor / Bulan
</div>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    if((".visitor").val() == "5,000") {
      $(".harga").value == "4000";
    }
  });
</script>
```

i have this script, how can I change the value on *harga* from *visitor*, when I choose selection from select box?

thank you before.

Comment: Add a `.change()` handler to the select, and put your `if` inside the handler?

Comment: Not directly helpful to your question, but consider losing the `<center>` tag in favor of CSS positioning on `div.main`.  Also, try `<br />` rather than `</br>`.

Comment: can you write again the script, please

Comment: i'm sorry wrong question.

Comment: Also, are you meaning to update the text of `div.harga`?  Because attempting to manipulate the `.value` property is not gonna work, because `value` isn't a property of the jQuery object you return in your script.  You could use `.text()`, or else `.harga` needs to belong to an form element of some sort.  And if you meant to have that be an input element, then you need to either use jQuery's `.val()` method to set it, or get that specific DOM node from the jQuery object, which then has a `value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `change` event like this

```
$('.visitor').change(function(){
        if($(this).val()  == '5,000'){
                // write your to do action here
        }
});
```